# Why do some answers don't have edit link?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, answers

Currently in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/226934/103134) of question [226923](https://superuser.com/q/226923/103134) I am seeing that there is no link to edit the answer, whereas just below that answer I can see that there is link to edit that answer.

Both answers are answered at almost same time with the difference of 4 minutes.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see, this is no duplicate of the linked question, and I would be interested in knowing the answer to the original question...

Answer (score 4):

Quoting directly from [Missing edit link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link)

> There are many options here:
>
> 1. You are not logged on and the post is 10 minutes old or less
> 2. There is already a pending edit on this post
> 3. The queue [is full](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue), only happens rarely on new SE sites with no moderators
> 4. You have been banned for a week cause you submitted many rejected edits
>
> Options 2, 3 and 4 only apply if you have less than [2,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit).